# what's the usage for trySet method in redisson rbucket

Tags: redis, redisson

I'm learning Redisson now, I have an example as below:

```
public class TestRedisson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress("//localhost:6379");

        RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);    
        RBucket<String> bucket = redisson.getBucket("test");
        bucket.set("123");

        boolean isUpdated = bucket.compareAndSet("123", "4934");    
        System.out.println("isUpdated:" + isUpdated);    
        System.out.println(bucket.get());

        String prevObject = bucket.getAndSet("321");    
        System.out.println("prevObject:" + prevObject);    
        System.out.println(bucket.get());

        boolean isSet = bucket.trySet("901");    
        System.out.println("isSet:" + isSet);    
        System.out.println(bucket.get());

        long objectSize = bucket.size();    
        System.out.println(objectSize);         
        redisson.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
isUpdated:true
4934
prevObject:4934
321
isSet:false
321
5
```

I'm puzzled about the usage for `trySet` method, why is failed in this example, I don't find any explanation in the Redisson API document for this method, and another question is why the `objectSize` is `5`? As the value of bucket is `321` now, I think the `objectSize` should be `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking into this myself too.

It looks like from the documentation it says:

> Try to save objects mapped by Redis key. If at least one of them is
>   already exist then don't set none of them.

So if the bucket already has an object, trySet will fail and return false. If the bucket is empty, trySet will succeed and set the value.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.redisson/redisson/3.4.1/org/redisson/api/RBuckets.html#trySet-java.util.Map-

Comment: OK, you're right, while why the bucket size is 5, not 3?

Comment: `bucket.size()` returns the size of object in bytes, not the length of the string. That just means asides from the 3 numbers each taking 1 byte, the object has 2 other bytes of data in it containing other information.